# How to create Auto Pull request trigger in AWS CodeCommit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-codecommit, comments

I am new to Code Commit and know a little about git.
I have root access to the repo
Basically, I want to maintain code Commit branch (master).

I want to implement trigger, (if possible) such as:

All developers need to create their own branch from "master" and when they want to push to "master" branch, a new Pull request gets created.

Not sure if possible (create gating), 
when I approve the pull request, it goes to master branch.
I hope I am clear 
A Million thanks

Comment: python would be best if possible

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

CodeCommit now supports branch level permissions. You can read more about it here

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/05/aws-codecommit-supports-branch-level-permissions/

or here

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/refining-access-to-branches-in-aws-codecommit/

---

There is currently no branch level permissions on a repository that would prevent someone from pushing specifically to master, or any other branch.

A number of customers are interested in this feature, your request will help us prioritize our work.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no way to add IAM permissions on branches. It’s one of the BIG pains of CodeCommit that makes it hard to implement - it drastically reduce security compared to all the other solutions on the marker